# Accord : le chat et le chien caché/cachés/cacher

Tags: orthographe

C'est quoi la bonne forme de la phrase suivante et pourquoi ?

> le chat et le chien caché / cachés / cacher

Merci d'avance.

Comment: Plus de contexte? Il est difficile de trancher sur un tout petit bout de phrase comme ça, quoique la troisième option (_cacher_) est plus qu'improbable.

Answer (score 2):

Les deux premières phrases sont possibles. Il faut savoir si le chat est caché ou pas.

La troisième l'est aussi, mais nettement plus douteuse car elle implique que la consommation des deux animaux est envisagée…

Comment: Je ne suis pas certaine de comprendre le commentaire au sujet de la troisième option... Pensez-vous à *kosher*? Dans quel cas ce serait kasher, ou casher, pas cacher.

Comment: Oui, bien sûr. L'orthographe choisie n'est pas standard mais c'était pour la blague... On trouve quand même beaucoup de « [viande cacher](http://www.123cacher.com/fr/manger-cacher/viande-cacher.html) » et autre variantes. Il y a aussi « cachère » qui lui est reconnu.

Comment: C'est ce que je pensais, mais je ne me souviens pas d'avoir vu « cacher » auparavant, mais faut dire que ce n'est pas un attribut auquel je porte particulièrement attention.

Answer (score 2):

Pour ajouter un peu au "pourquoi" de la réponse de jilliagre : Il faut que tout adjectif s'accorde avec le nom qu'il décrit. Ou plus précisémment avec la *phrase nominale* qu'il décrit.

L'accord peut être du genre ou du nombre.

Il y a deux phrases nominales possibles ici selon la division de la phrase :

> Le chat et [ ( le chien ) caché ] — seul le chien est caché, donc accord au singulier
>
> [ ( Le chat et le chien ) cachés ] — tous les deux sont cachés, donc accord au pluriel

"Cacher" en tant que translitération du terme hébreu "[kashrut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashrut)" (כשרות) est carrément un autre adjectif mais marche aussi, comme jilliagre en offre l'interprétation. :)

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse, une autre petite question. dans le cas d'adjectif, je comprend qu'il s'accord, mais est ce qu'on peut utiliser le verbe **cacher**, et pourquoi (oui ou non)

Comment: Pourquoi voudrais-tu utiliser le verbe à l'infinitif ? Ça n'a aucun sens.

Comment: Tout à fait ; il ne s'agirait pas ici d'un verbe à l'infinitif mais de la translitération du terme "kashrut", ce qui est un adjectif. Que ce terme et "cacher" verbe infinitif soient des homographes est une coïncidence.